# How can I execute a list of binaries from a pipe with desired parameters?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm doing a find and locating several executables that I want to run with -v.  I tried something like this:

find *somefilters* | xargs -I % % -v

Unfortuntely, xargs seems to require that the "utility" be a fixed binary rather than a binary provided by stdin.  Does anyone have a recipe for doing this command line magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-exec` primary:

```
find ... -exec '{}' -v \;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had thought that the limitations xargs places on the parameter the docs labels as "utility" would be similar to the same labeled parameter in the docs for find.  Shouldn't have assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way around this - use `xargs` to write a shell script for you:

```
find somefilters | xargs -n 1 -I % echo % -v | ${SHELL}
```

That won't work out so well if any of the programs require interactivity, but if the `-v` option is just to spit out the version numbers or something (one common meaning, the other being a verbose flag), it should work fine.